# Terraform apply -refresh stuck in instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have created 2 instances with terraform, and after that destroyed them.

After a change I did another terraform apply.

This time it is stuck in destroy status of one of the previous ones.

Because of that, in the second apply command it created only one instance.

Since one of the instances stuck in shutting down mode, it doesnt terminate.

Now the terraform state stuck with only one instance, and because one of them is still destroy mode, i can't have my second instance come online.

I have looked online, it says open a support case with amazon, but I wanted to check first if there is a shorter/easier way of solving this problem.

Thank you.

Rafet.

[image]

Comment: terraform destroy until everything is terminated. Closing the post.

Answer (score 0):

terraform destroy until process completed. then apply again.